# Error: Cannot find module "rxjs/operators" in Ionic Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

[image]

Im trying to run my Ionic project. It was working fine until some days ago, now I just can't run it, whatever I do. this error shows up! I tried removing Rxjs from package.json and node_modules, also commented out all the place I used Rxjs, still this error shows up. Tried in Ubuntu 16.04 with Node 8.9.0 and npm 4.5.0.
Also tried the same running in windows still shows the same error! How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try reinstalling rxjs of version 5.5.3 or newer

```
npm install @reactivex/rxjs@5.5.3
```

this issue seems to be fixed in version 5.5.3 https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2971

Comment: It works! Thank you. I tried 5.5.4 in local npm earlier, didn't work! Thanks a lot!